# Confusion: Arrangement Probability Problems

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

**Consider the following 3 problems.**

**Problem 1.**

> The 9 letters in the word ALLIGATOR are arranged in random order. Find the probability the two Ls are together and there are exactly 6 letters between the As?

**Problem 2.**

> Four letters are randomly selected from the 8 letters of the word TOMORROW. Find the probability the selection contains at least one O and at least one R?

**Problem 3.**

> Five of the 11 letters in the word REQUIREMENT are selected. How many possible selections contain at least two Es and at least one R?

**Consider problem 2**. What is unclear to me here, is that the markscheme treats the Os and the Rs as being distinct. That is the case OOR_ is calculated using $(3C2)(2C1)(3C1)$ rather than just being $(3C1)$. Why can we treat the Os and the Rs as being distinct?

**Consider problem 1.** Here instead of treating the As and Ls as distinct, they treat them the same. It seems that these problems contradict one another. How come, the As and Ls are not treated distinct over here? When working out the problem, the total number of arrangements is calculated using $\frac{9!}{2!2!}$. However, to me isn't the total number of arrangements $9!$? Even though some cases may appear identical here, we must account for them as they all have a probability of occurring. So once again, shouldn't we treat the As and Ls distinct similar to problem 2?

**Problem 3** does not treat the letters as distinct. However, as it is possible **selections**, I assume two scenarios that appear identical are treated the same. When dealing with **probability**, mustn't we account for the cases that appear identical as well? Problem 1 seems to contradict this and has made me confused.

**EDIT:** Could this be a confusion between arrangements and selections? Are these calculated slightly differently?

Comment: Whether you do treat them as distinct or not shouldn't matter for probability so long as you are consistent for both numerator and denominator